# Mathjax fractions and dollar signs incompatible, fraction display also off

Tags: mathjax

I am trying to render dollar signs in Mathjax in a fraction.
I am able to use dollar signs elsewhere in Mathjax, by wrapping them in a $, but  in the fraction - which I believe does not like any html- it will not work with the  trick, so I do not use it there - they do not display.
2 of them render as a blank space- so Mathjax interpreted it as an expression and did not display, but any odd number ie 1, 3, 5 will display as gibberish. Seems like an uncompleted expression - ie one dollar sign but no end dollar sign, so it gets confused. Any solutions anyone? I have tried everything- escaping it, etc, etc.

I also am using a custom font, and when it displays ,it has the numerator and denominators a tad bit too far up and down from the fraction bar. Anyone know of any way to tighten this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$\frac{\$100.00}{\$10.00}$`, which is the usual TeX approach to handling dollar signs within an expression.  If that doesn't work for you, then you will have to give more details about the situation where you are using MathJax (such as your MathJax configuration block, and whether you are using a content-management system to enter your text, etc.).

As for the font issue, you will need to give more details about what.  MathJax is only designed to work with the fonts that is comes with, and it has the bounding box information only for those fonts.  MathJax doesn't have the bounding box information for other fonts, so it will have to guess about that, and likely gets it wrong.

Comment: I was using this that worked well when I escaped the $ signs:         var tNewString  = "&#92" + "(" + "&#92" + "frac{" + ""+ tTop2 + "}{" +""+ tBot2 + "}" + "&#92" + ")";                                     I now have to use a custom font- and it seems to make it not work:               var tNewString  = "&#92" + "(" + "&#92" + "frac{"+ "&#92" +"style{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;}{"+ "&#92" +"text{" + tTop +"}}}{"+"&#92"+ "style{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;}{"+ "&#92" +"text{"+ tBot + "}}}"+ "&#92" + ")" - too many escapes?

Comment: Without knowing what `tTop` and `tBot` are, or how you have defined `\(` and `\)`, it is hard to tell what will happen.  When I make values for these, your example works for me.  Perhaps you can be clearer what "make it not work" means.  Do you get no output?  An error message?  Some output but not what you expect?  Note that your original used `tTop2` rather than `tTop` (and same for `tBot`).  Is that correct?  As an aside, you should use `;` at the end of your entities, as in `"&#92;"` not `"&#92"`.

Comment: Your string could be more easily handled as `"\\(\\frac{\\style{font-family:Arial, sans-serif}{\text{"+tTop+"}}}{\\style{font-family:Arial,sans-serif}{\\text{"+tBot+"}}}\\)"`.  If you must use the entities, you can put them all in one string, too, as `"&#92;(&#92;frac{...`.

Comment: Hi- I am getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL " when I run your string- What happens with mine original one when it errors out is that it renders the fraction as text , like: frac{"+ "&#92" +"style{font-family:reportschool, TeX, Arial, sans-serif;}{"+  "&#92" +"text{" etc- Thanks BTW- I will put semicolons at end of entities and try now.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with how you are getting the string into the page.  You haven't shown enough of your code to really tell.  Perhaps if you set something up in jsFiddle of codebin, we could get it worked out.